# Converting string to bytes

Tags: python, python-3.x, shell

I have a file that have this format:

`username
password (base64 encoded)
id`

I have to read this password (base64 encoded) and decode it to pass as a paramater in the password to authenticate.
The problem is, when I read this password it is being readed as string and I get an error when I try to decode because this is expecting to be bytes.

```
def getSecret(self):
    home = expanduser("~/.user/credentials")
    with open(home,"r") as file:
        self.password = list(file)[1]
        self.password = base64.b64decode(self.password)

        return self.password


conn = User()
decode = base64.b64decode(conn.getSecret())
print(decode)
```

But this is returning a string and should be bytes, when I try to decode this i got this error

```
return binascii.a2b_base64(s)
binascii.Error: Incorrect padding
```

How can I read and decode this?

Thank you.

Comment: Is there perhaps a newline or some other space characters in the string? Print it out (for yourself!) with some letters around it: `print("X{}X".format(password_b64))` and check for extras.

Comment: Why is the password base 64 encoded? That's essentially the same as plain text.

Comment: `getSecret()` returns the decoded base 64 string, then it looks like you're trying to decode it again.

Comment: I got the length of my base64 encoded string and when I read the same string from the file they are different in size.

If I type the encoded string i got a size of 12, but when I read the string from file I got a size of 15.

I removed all spaces with strip and can't get the size to match.

Imagine this is my encoded string print(len(b'dhisdjflisdfsdifjsdif')) = 12
if I read it I get 15.

Why is this happening? there's no spaces.

Answer (score 1):

You have a Python `string` that you want to decode:

```
>>> password_b64='c2VjcmV0\n'
```

The `binascii.a2b_base64` function will do that (**NOTE:** `a2b`):

```
>>> binascii.a2b_base64(password_b64)
b'secret'
```

But it returns a `bytes` object, not a `string` object. So you have to decode the bytes somehow. The obvious way is to presume they are UTF-8,
and invoke the `.decode(encoding)` method on the resulting `bytes`:

```
>>> binascii.a2b_base64(password_b64).decode("utf-8")
'secret'
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, just had to remove the b'' from the string and everything worked.
Thank you very much everyone.